# scrollTop() shows result only after page refresh

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Hii I am working on jquery but my code working in a weird manner.
Here is my code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        if($(window).scrollTop() >= 50) {
            $("h1").fadeIn("slow");
        };
    })
```

I want my text to fadein when scroll. But my text appear ony after I refresh page after scrolling.
I dont know Why what is wrong with my code.

Comment: Hi. You need to wrap this logic in a scroll event.

Comment: Ohh sorry I didn't knew about that. I am new here.

Comment: It's okay, friend. Have a nice day :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I wrote above in the comment, you need to wrap your logic in a window scrolling event. Like this:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if($(window).scrollTop() >= 50) {
      $("h1").fadeIn("slow");
    }
})
```

I made an example for you by specifying the `position: sticky` for the `h1` tag so that you can visually understand how the code works.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if($(window).scrollTop() >= 50) {
      $("h1").fadeIn("slow");
    }
  })
})
```

```css
body {
  height: 3000px;
}

h1 {
  display: none;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Test_Text</h1>
```

Comment: @NeerajChimwal, no problem, friend.